# Parsing part of a json object with multi levels using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

If you open the URL, you'll see that it's a very long string of sub objects. I want to extract the values for the 70 position. So far I've been able to extract the first tree without a problem ... But if you go deeper then I don’t get any feedback at all. Please check the code below and tell me, what am I doing wrong?

```
$url= "https://bwt.cbp.gov/api/waittimes";

$port = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$data = json_decode($port); // decode the JSON feed

echo $data[69]->port_name.'<br>';
echo $data[69]->port_status.'<br>';
echo $data[69]->passenger_vehicle_lanes->maximum_lanes.'<br>';
echo $data[69]->passenger_vehicle_lanes->standard_lanes->lanes_open.'<br>';
```

Comment: Hi, can you try to change `json_decode($port, true);` like this and access it like in array `echo $data[69]['passenger_vehicle_lanes']['maximum_lanes'].'<br>';`

Comment: Can you post json data or object?

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly. Boy am I glad  you helped me.

Comment: I tried the code above (PHP 7.0.13) and I get the correct data
"San Ysidro, Open, 24" from what I can see.  There's no other code in the script that could interfere?

Comment: Well yes that's as far as it goes. The fourth line is not showing the results.. (lanes_open)

Comment: Ah, but isn't the `lanes_open` element is empty for that port? Seems to be the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working for me:

```
$url= "https://bwt.cbp.gov/api/waittimes";

$port = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$data = json_decode($port, true); // decode the JSON feed


echo "There are ".count($data)."Ports".PHP_EOL;


$found=false;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     //EDIT AFTER COMMENT**
     if($value['port_number']==250401){
        echo $value['port_name'].' '.$value['crossing_name'].PHP_EOL;
        $found=true;
        break;
     }
}


if(!$found) echo "couldn't find port #";
```

Comment: Nice, but I was looking for a specific chunk of information within the string, I like your code tough, good job.

Comment: This was just an example on how to scan your data... About the specific part you're looking for at the 70th position... I would be careful about relying on the order provided by an external service... I recommend to find it through a unique ID, not by position....

Comment: Ok... now that sounds interesting... How would you go about it.. if<port_number>250401 then echo <port_name>and<crossing_name/>And<hours> (Not meant to be rude).. You really stirred my interest.

Comment: Since your answer doesnt fit for indexing on port_number the only solution I see is to scan the answer and return the wanted result... see my edit

Comment: I added also a check if nothing is found.... breaking the loop is ok if you're sure there's only one result.... otherwise you should continue and return the whole list of matching results...

Comment: Glad to be helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

can you try to change `json_decode($port, true);` (true will change object to array and it will be better to access it) like this and access it like in array `echo $data[69]['passenger_vehicle_lanes']['maximum_lanes'].'<br>';`

Comment: Excellent approach,it worked perfectly. Thank You Olexander, You rock.